# Which point in time is reflected in the files of an EC2 AMI taken while rebooting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, reboot

If you take an AMI from an EC2, and the AMI takes, say, 1 hour to be available; and you choose the option not to skip the reboot.

All the files in the AMI will:
a) reflect their exact condition from the time the EC2 was rebooted? or
b) they may reflect any condition in this 1 hour interval which is what it took for the AMI to be available.

I always considered option a, but I'm not so sure any more, specially after I noticed that when you take an AMI in the console, it gives this message:

"*Currently creating AMI ..... Check that the AMI status is 'Available' before deleting the instance or carrying out other actions related to this AMI.*"

I want to know if it's safe to start applying changes in an EC2 instance after an AMI is requested and the EC2 rebooted, but before the AMI is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) will contain a copy of the disk at it was at **exactly at the point in time when the API call was issued**.

Or, if the instance is **rebooted as part of the image creation**, it will contain a copy of the disk as it was between the time when the operating system shutdown and when the operating system started again.

The time taken for an AMI to become available involves copying disk blocks to the Snapshot used by the AMI. Any disk changes during that time will *not* be reflected in the AMI. This is possible because the disk is virtual. (It's a bit like a database being able to roll-back due to the use of log files.)

From [Create Amazon EBS snapshots - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html):

> Snapshots occur asynchronously; the **point-in-time snapshot** is created immediately, but the status of the snapshot is pending until the snapshot is complete (when all of the modified blocks have been transferred to Amazon S3), which can take several hours for large initial snapshots or subsequent snapshots where many blocks have changed. While it is completing, **an in-progress snapshot is not affected by ongoing reads and writes to the volume**... snapshots only capture data that has been written to your Amazon EBS volume **at the time the snapshot command is issued**.

Comment: Hello buddy. Did you take that from the AWS docs? If yes, can you show me where? I could not find it. I always had the same understanding as you. But recently some peers put me in doubt. And I cannot find any explicit information in the AWS docs eliminating this doubt.

Comment: Added a document reference.